# jQueryUI Draggable with iframeFix prevents click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have a problem using jQueryUI Draggable and detecting both drag and clicks on an element when iFramefix flag is set to true.

http://jsfiddle.net/xBB5x/11706/

Code:

```
$(function(){
    $("#dummy").draggable({iframeFix: true});
  $("#dummy").click(function() {
  alert("hey ho");
  });
});
```

From what I found out during some testing and research that the iframeFix creates some div overlay above the iframe so dragging will be smooth but that prevents clicks from being triggered.

Any idea's?

Comment: Well, isn't that what you are trying to achieve by using iframeFix? Preventing clicks from being fired?

Comment: Nope, the element isn't inside the iframe. any way - by using zIndex'es I was able to make the elements above the iframe div and catch the clicks.